# Using macros to implement a generic vector in C. Is this a good idea?

Tags: c, vector, data-structures, macros, c-preprocessor

I am a programmer who knows both C and C++. I have used both languages in my own projects but I do not know which one I prefer.

When I program in C the feature that I miss the most from C++ is `std::vector` from the STL (Standard Template Library)

I still haven't figured out how I should represent growing arrays in C. Up to this point I duplicated my memory allocation code all over the place in my projects. I do not like code duplication and I know that it is bad practice so this does not seems like a very good solution to me.

I thought about this problem some time ago and came up with the idea to implement a generic vector using preprocessor macros.

This is how the implementation looks:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H_
#define VECTOR_H_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Declare a vector of type `TYPE`. */
#define VECTOR_OF(TYPE) struct { \
    TYPE *data; \
    size_t size; \
    size_t capacity; \
}

/* Initialize `VEC` with `N` capacity. */
#define VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY(VEC, N) do { \
    (VEC).data = malloc((N) * sizeof(*(VEC).data)); \
    if (!(VEC).data) { \
        fputs("malloc failed!\n", stderr); \
        abort(); \
    } \
    (VEC).size = 0; \
    (VEC).capacity = (N); \
} while (0)

/* Initialize `VEC` with zero elements. */
#define VECTOR_INIT(VEC) VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY(VEC, 1)

/* Get the amount of elements in `VEC`. */
#define VECTOR_SIZE(VEC) (VEC).size

/* Get the amount of elements that are allocated for `VEC`. */
#define VECTOR_CAPACITY(VEC) (VEC).capacity

/* Test if `VEC` is empty. */
#define VECTOR_EMPTY(VEC) ((VEC).size == 0)

/* Push `VAL` at the back of the vector. This function will reallocate the buffer if
   necessary. */
#define VECTOR_PUSH_BACK(VEC, VAL) do { \
    if ((VEC).size + 1 > (VEC).capacity) { \
        size_t n = (VEC).capacity * 2; \
        void *p = realloc((VEC).data, n * sizeof(*(VEC).data)); \
        if (!p) { \
            fputs("realloc failed!\n", stderr); \
            abort(); \
        } \
        (VEC).data = p; \
        (VEC).capacity = n; \
    } \
    (VEC).data[VECTOR_SIZE(VEC)] = (VAL); \
    (VEC).size += 1; \
} while (0)

/* Get the value of `VEC` at `INDEX`. */
#define VECTOR_AT(VEC, INDEX) (VEC).data[INDEX]

/* Get the value at the front of `VEC`. */
#define VECTOR_FRONT(VEC) (VEC).data[0]

/* Get the value at the back of `VEC`. */
#define VECTOR_BACK(VEC) (VEC).data[VECTOR_SIZE(VEC) - 1]

#define VECTOR_FREE(VEC) do { \
    (VEC).size = 0; \
    (VEC).capacity = 0; \
    free((VEC).data); \
} while(0)

#endif /* !defined VECTOR_H_ */
```

This code goes in the header file called `"vector.h"`.

Note that it does miss some functionality (like `VECTOR_INSERT` and `VECTOR_ERASE`) but I think that it is good enough to show my concept.

The use of the vector looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    VECTOR_OF(int) int_vec;
    VECTOR_OF(double) dbl_vec;
    int i;

    VECTOR_INIT(int_vec);
    VECTOR_INIT(dbl_vec);

    for (i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
        VECTOR_PUSH_BACK(int_vec, i);
        VECTOR_PUSH_BACK(dbl_vec, i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        printf("int_vec[%d] = %d\n", i, VECTOR_AT(int_vec, i));
        printf("dbl_vec[%d] = %f\n", i, VECTOR_AT(dbl_vec, i));
    }

    VECTOR_FREE(int_vec);
    VECTOR_FREE(dbl_vec);

    return 0;
}
```

It uses the same allocation rules as `std::vector` (the size starts as `1` and then doubles each time that is required).

To my surprise I found out that this code runs more than twice as fast as the same code written using `std::vector` **and** generates a smaller executable! (compiled with GCC and G++ using `-O3` in both cases).

My questions to you are:

- Are there any serious faults with this approach?
- Would you recommend using this in a serious project?
- If not then I would like you to explain **why** and tell me what a better alternative would be.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your questions without knowing **how** your macros are implemented and what is your intended use case.

Comment: Why don't you write functions instead? there is no real advantage in using macros for this, except probably in very limited cases.

Comment: I can't speak for your implementation, but `queue.h` does a similar thing with lists and queues.  http://linux.die.net/man/3/queue

Comment: I wrote this [similar thing for linked lists](https://github.com/udp/list).

Comment: The reason I do not use functions is because functions cannot be "generic" in C. Good idea to include the source code. I will do that, just wait a minute!

Comment: I have added the source code now. I hope that it is all bug free!

Comment: `I [...]know both C and C++. [...] I do not know which one I prefer.` If you can choose between `C` and `C++` use `C++` no questions about it.

Comment: @bolov, it depends, I don't like c++ for example, I am force to work with it now, which is making me hate it even more. So I would say, it depends on what you need and what you want to do. And also if there was really no discussion, then why are there so many great c applications being developed in the present?

Comment: @iharob I understand not choosing `C++` if the alternative is `Java` or `Python` or something like that. But choosing `C` over `C++` I find it hard to wrap my head around it, unless you don't know very well `C++` in which case indeed sticking to what you know better can be the better choice. But he said he knows both `C` and `C++`.

Comment: @bolov: C has better tool support than C++; see, for instance, Coccinelle or Frama-C.  The only C++ tools I know of are compilers.

Comment: @tmyklebu this doesn't fall in the category "I can choose both". If you don't have a mature tool for `C++` but you do have for `C` of course you have to go with `C`. My point was that if **you can choose between them** and **you know them both** C++ is clearly the better alternative.

Comment: It's not a matter of which language you know more, it is about which one is more suitable for the task, this could become a very long discussion, in fact endless, because it's a matter of opinion and taste, but I hate the way c++ forces one to write code anyway, so I love c. And also, often you find c++ programmers with very low level, that's very unlikely in a c programmer. I have read things like `I find c++ quite ugly` written by a very famous person, but have never read anything similar about c.

Comment: Your `VECTOR_BACK` macros contains a small but significant flaw.

Comment: @bolov While I do agree that programming in `C++` can be less painful than in `C`. I still like to use `C` in hobby projects because I think that the language is more elegantly designed. `C` also seems to be better established in the free and open-source world so I want to get proficient with it. I do not mind `C++`. It is a great tool but there is something that I find appealing with `C`. I am also learning `Perl` and `Python`. `Python` also seems like a great language that I think I will start to use in the future.

Comment: @Joachim Ohh, I did not see that. Thanks for letting me know. It is fixed now!

Comment: I'm using your code from [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101816/generic-vector-implementation-in-c-using-macros). Have you tried testing your implementation of vector in 2-D? I believe it only works in the 1-D case (as you've shown in your test source code. I was able to initialize a `VECTOR_OF(VECTOR_OF(char))` easily enough, but I wasn't able to `VECTOR_PUSH_BACK` a `VECTOR_OF(char)` to this 2-D vector. Here's the compilation error I get: `incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct <anonymous>' from type 'struct <anonymous>' vec->data[vec->size] = val`.

Comment: Hello! Yeah, I never thought of that problem. I can't think of a way to make it work because C does not permit assignment between anonymous structures. These type inconsistencies is obviously a big disadvantage for doing this :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> To my surprise I found out that this code runs more than twice as fast as the same code written using std::vector and generates a smaller executable! (compiled with GCC and G++ using -O3 in both cases).

There are three reasons why your C version is faster/smaller than the C++ version:

1. The implementation of `new` in the standard C++ library that is used by `g++` is suboptimal. If you implement `void* operator new (size_t size)` as a call-through to `malloc()` you get better performance than with the built-in version.
2. If `realloc()` has to use a new chunk of memory, it moves the old data over in the fashion of `memmove()`, i. e. it ignores the logical structure of the data and simply moves the bits. That operation can easily be accelerated to the point that the memory bus is the bottleneck. `std::vector<>`, on the other hand, must take care of possibly calling constructors/destructors correctly, it can't just call through to `memmove()`. In the case of `int` and `double` that boils down to moving the data one `int`/`double` at a time, the loop is in the code generated for the `std::vector<>`. That is not too bad, but its worse than using SSE instructions which a good `memmove()` implementation will do.
3. The `realloc()` function is part of the standard C library which is dynamically linked to your executable. The memory management code generated by `std::vector<>`, however, is precisely that: generated. As such, it must be a part of your executable.

> Are there any serious faults with this approach?

This is a matter of taste, but I think, the approach is smelly: Your macro definitions are far away from their uses, and they do not all behave like simple constants or inline function. In fact, they act suspiciously like elements of a programming language (i. e. templates), which is not a good thing for preprocessor macros. It is generally a bad idea to try to modify the language by use of the preprocessor.

You also have a serious issue with your macro implementations: The `VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY(VEC, N)` macro evaluates its `VEC` argument four times and the `N` argument twice. Now think about what happens if you do a call `VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY(foo, baz++)`: The size stored in the `capacity` field of the new vector will be larger than the size of the memory allocated for it. The line with the `malloc()` call will increment the `baz` variable, and that new value will be stored in the `capacity` member before `baz` is incremented a second time. You should write all macros in a way that the evaluate their arguments exactly once.

> Would you recommend using this in a serious project?

I think, I wouldn't bother. The `realloc()` code is trivial enough that some replications won't hurt too much. But again, your mileage may vary.

> If not then I would like you to explain why and tell me what a better alternative would be.

As I said before, I wouldn't bother trying to write a general container class in the style of `std::vector<>`, neither by (ab)using the preprocessor, nor by (ab)using `void*`.

But I would take a close look at the memory handling on the system that I write for: With many kernels, it is extremely unlikely that you ever get a return value of `NULL` out of a `malloc()`/`realloc()` call. They over-commit their memory, making promises they cannot be certain to be able to fulfill. And when they realize that they can't back up their promises, they start shooting processes via the OOM-killer. On such a system (linux is one of them), your error handling is simply pointless. It will never get executed. As such, you can avoid the pain of adding it and replicating it to all the places where you need a dynamically growing array.

My memory reallocation code in C usually looks something like this:

```
if(size == capacity) {
    array = realloc(array, (capacity *= 2) * sizeof(*array));
}
array[size++] = ...;
```

Without the functionless error handling code, this is so short that it can safely be replicated as many times as it is needed.

Comment: "I wouldn't bother trying to write a general container class in the style of std::vector<>" What do you recommend instead? What do you use if you want a container that can contain int's and another one that can contain e.g a user defined struct?

Comment: @EarlofLemongrab I would use exactly what I've shown. An `if()` statement containing a `realloc()` call and a subsequent `array[size++]`. It's quite idiomatic code in C. I've also detailed the reasons why I think this is sufficient for the vast majority of cases in the last paragraphs.

Comment: And what about more complex data structures?

Comment: @EarlofLemongrab As long as you don't store pointers to the arrays' elements somewhere, the `realloc()` works like a charm on arrays of elements of any type. That's really the only downside of `realloc()` that it invalidates any pointers that refer to the possibly moved region. Exactly like `std::vector<>::push_back()` invalidates all iterators/pointers/references to its elements. Also note that I used `*array` as the argument to `sizeof()`: This derives the size directly from the array's element type. You can change the type of `array` without changing the `realloc()` call.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any serious faults with this approach?

You're reinventing templates in a way that interacts poorly with C's type system.  For instance, your `VECTOR` types are anonymous, so I can't write a function that takes a `VECTOR_OF(int)` as a parameter.

Even if you do name your types somehow, I wouldn't be able to write a generic *function*---something that takes a `VECTOR_OF(T)` for arbitrary `T` and does something with it.

These might not be serious faults, but there's a hundred minor drawbacks like this to every generics-using-macros approach I've seen in C.  This all comes up because the language doesn't try to support generic programming at all.

> Would you recommend using this in a serious project?

Sure; you can develop a serious project using container types like this, and they won't even necessarily get in your face.  You'll probably need to traffic in `void *`'s to pass these things around, and that leads to some casting that's a little bit error-prone.

Comment: Good answer. I will add that you can use `typedef VECTOR_OF(blah) Blah_vector;` and use `Blah_vector` in a function parameter. It is quite ugly though.

Comment: @elias: But then `Blah_vector` is incompatible with things declared as `VECTOR_OF(blah)`.  So you'd need to "instantiate the template" for every type you care about in advance.  This can lead to subtle errors that won't be detected by the compiler if you're incautious about your names and you have multiple translation units.  (Basically, there's a reason templates exist in C++, and this is it.)

Answer (score 1):

> My questions to you are:
>      Are there any serious faults with this approach?

Yes, you're trying to reinvent [the wheel](http://www.bsdua.org/libbsdua.html#vpool).

> Would you recommend using this in a serious project?

No, especially since your speed up generally indicated you might be missing some security checks.

> If not then I would like you to explain why and tell me what a better alternative would be.

VPool from above, or something else like that. If you search for "C growable buffer", you'll find several hints on stackoverflow and via google

Comment: Note my down-vote, but: The vpool at http://bsdua.org/ is a byte-oriented abstraction, whereas the vector code presented in the question deals with other types than byte-stream.  That's not to say vpool can't be used; it just isn't really equivalent to the vector code above.

Comment: it is, with a heavy heart, that I accept your downvote, @JonathanLeffler ;) what you're saying is absolutely true; so he's stuck with one of the other implementations

Comment: Beg pardon — 'Note' should have been 'Not' (oops!).  The rest remains accurate, though.

Comment: Well, that's a relief, then :) I hope OP finds a well-tested implementation that suits the needs encountered -- pretty sure there even is something like that a few times in the linux kernel (which at least would make it kind of peer-reviewed).